# Sesamanuel package issue to put the chapter title to break in two lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

This is the result to expect:

[image: excerpt from sesamath]

This is my work so far and I got issue when I put the two backlashes to go to the new line. Use XelaTeX for compiling...

```
\documentclass[nocrop]{sesamanuel}

\let\ifluatex\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\NewThema{A}{a}{analyse}{Analyse}{ANALYSE}{PartieFonction}{A3}

\themaA
\colorlet{ChapterNumSquare1Color}{PartieFonction}
\chapter{Fonctions\\Numériques}
\cours



my first chapter goes here... chapter  goes here...




\themaG
\colorlet{ChapterNumSquare1Color}{PartieGeometrie}
\chapter{Nombres\\Complexes}
\cours

my second chapter goes here...

\NewThema{PS}{ps}{probabilités statistiques}{Probabilités Statistiques}{PROBABILITES \\ STATISTIQUES}{PartieStatistique}{U1}
\themaPS

\colorlet{ChapterNumSquare1Color}{PartieStatistique}
\chapter{Probabilités\\Statistiques}
\cours

my third chapter ....


\end{document}
```

after compiling it this is the result :

[image: my result]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that `\NewThema` does not deal well with the linebreak. As a workaround you could use `\newcommand*\themaPS{...}` to define your new theme.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[nocrop]{sesamanuel}

\let\ifluatex\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\themaPS{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \def\smc@thema{probabilités statistiques}%
  \def\smc@themacap{PROBABILIT\'ES\\ STATISTIQUES}%
  \def\smc@thema@init{ps}%
  \def\smc@thema@initcap{PS}%
  \smc@themaSColor
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\themaPS
\chapter{Partie Statistique}

my first chapter goes here... chapter  goes here...

\end{document}
```

[image]